# Does both or Do both?

Tags: usage

> **Does** both kidneys work together.
>
> **Do** both kidneys work together.

Are both sentences correct?

Answer (score 2):

Only the second sentence has correct subject/verb agreement.

Here are some examples:

1. **Do** the oranges smell nice?
2. **Does** that orange smell nice?
3. **Do** Americans like tennis?
4. **Does** he like tennis?
5. **Does** her kidney work?
6. **Do** both kidneys work together?
7. **Does** each kidney work?

The last example is tricky.  In this sentence the "each" implies that we are focusing on one kidney at a time, so the sentence could be interpreted:  Does the first kidney work? Yes.  Does the second kidney work?  Yes.